# Java - get opening and closing time for each day from string

Tags: java, json

I am programming one application which gather data from JSON. And I have one string, that is called "opening_hours" from this string I need to get info about each day in week (I don't know how to explain...)

Example is: `"Mon: 11:00 – 22:00 Tue: 11:00 – 22:00 Wed: 11:00 – 22:00 Thu: 11:00 – 5:00 Fri: 10:00 – 6:00 Sat: 11:00 – 6:00 Sun: 12:00 – 23:00"`

And from this example I should get 14 variables or an array, which for example, would look like this:

```
[0]=> 11:00
[1]=> 22:00
[2]=> 11:00
etc..
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!
And I'm sorry - my english is not very good.

Comment: Can your provide some code? It's better to post youe java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions from package "java.util.regex". They're the best solution if you're 100% sure that the String will always use the same format.

This answer is not the best place for a regex tutorial, so have a look at Javadoc here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

and java tutorials on regexes here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Comment: Okay, thank you. I already thought that regular expressions will be the thing I should learn. I have been in programming just a year, so I haven't learned regex yet.

Comment: If this anwer is the right one for you, plese upvote and mark it as best answer, so that others know that this is no longer an open issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution:

```
private static enum WeekDay {
    Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun
}

private static class DaySchedule {
    WeekDay weekDay;
    LocalTime startTime;
    LocalTime endTime;

    public DaySchedule(WeekDay weekDay, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime) {
        this.weekDay = weekDay;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return weekDay + " : " + startTime + " - " + endTime;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final String in = "Mon: 11:00 – 22:00 Tue: 11:00 – 22:00 Wed: 11:00 – 22:00 " +
            "Thu: 11:00 – 5:00 Fri: 10:00 – 6:00 Sat: 11:00 – 6:00 Sun: 12:00 – 23:00";

    final Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.on(" ").omitEmptyStrings().trimResults().split(in);

    final Iterable<String> scheduleTokens = Iterables.filter(tokens, new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(String input) {
            return input.length() > 2;
        }
    });

    final DateTimeFormatter localTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
    final List<DaySchedule> schedule = Lists.newArrayList();

    final Iterator<String> it = scheduleTokens.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        final WeekDay day = WeekDay.valueOf(it.next().replaceAll(":", ""));
        final LocalTime startTime = localTimeFormatter.parseLocalTime(it.next());
        final LocalTime endTime = localTimeFormatter.parseLocalTime(it.next());

        schedule.add(new DaySchedule(day, startTime, endTime));
    }

    System.out.println(schedule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `Pattern` en `Matcher`

```
    String info = "Mon: 11:00 – 22:00 Tue: 11:00 – 22:00 Wed: 11:00 – 22:00 Thu: 11:00 – 5:00 Fri: 10:00 – 6:00 Sat: 11:00 – 6:00 Sun: 12:00 – 23:00";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(5:00|6:00|10:00|11:00|12:00|22:00|23:00)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(info);
    List<String> theList = new ArrayList();
    while(m.find()) {
        theList.add(m.group());
    }
    theList.stream().forEach((item) -> {
        System.out.print(item + ", ");
    });
```

prints out:
 `11:00, 22:00, 11:00, 22:00, 11:00, 22:00, 11:00, 5:00, 10:00, 6:00, 11:00, 6:00, 12:00, 23:00`